# Python print statement changes behavior of code?

Tags: python, wxpython

**The weirdness:** After some experimenting I've concluded that putting in a useless line (`print "hi"`, or `x = 1`) ANYWHERE in the code below makes it work correctly.

What's going on? I'd love to understand what about how Python is processing this code that's causing this weird behavior.

**Some context:** I'm writing a gui in wxpython. I have this function (see below) which causes a tool to change icons when pressed (by removing the tool and adding it back in with a different icon).

The code shown below causes the button to switch icons correctly the first time, then the second time the toolbar seems to come up disabled. I had assumed it was a problem with the code, so I put in a print statement, which, to my surprise, fixed the problem.

```
def configure_itunes_button(self):
    '''
    Configures the itunes button to either sync or unsync depending on whether itunes is currently synced
    '''
    if self.iTunesTool:
        id = self.iTunesTool.GetId()
        self.toolbar.DeleteTool(id)
    else:
        id = self.toolbar.GetToolsCount() + 1

    if self._is_itunes_synced_locally:
        self.iTunesTool = self.toolbar.AddSimpleTool(id, wx.Bitmap('images\\iTunes.png'), "Sync iTunes Library", "Sync all iTunes music and playlists to Sookbox.")
    else:
        self.iTunesTool = self.toolbar.AddSimpleTool(id, wx.Bitmap('images\\trash.gif'), "Stop syncing iTunes Library", "Stop syncing all iTunes music and playlists to Sookbox.")

    self.Bind(wx.EVT_TOOL, self.onITunesSync, self.iTunesTool)
    self.toolbar.Realize()
```

Comment: Does removing the `print` leave your code in a working state? Then you probably forgot to save the previous version of the file, or forgot to restart your program and were running older code still.

Comment: Instead of using prints to debug your application, try using [pdb](http://pythonconquerstheuniverse.wordpress.com/2009/09/10/debugging-in-python/) instead

Comment: @Martijn Pieters No, if I remove the print the code no longer works. I definitely saved. Good thing to check though :)

Answer (score 0):

I would try using SetToolNormalBitmap rather than deleting the button. Then call toolbar.Realize(). See also https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/wxpython-users/m11YfTdjVjw

You may need to call self.Layout or self.Refresh too.

Alternatively, you might want to take a look at FlatMenu which is a pure Python implementation of the wxPython menu and toolbar. It would allow easier hacking.

Comment: Thanks, I tried that before going with this approach, however I couldn't get it to work for whatever reason (with various combinations of Layout and Refresh).